# How to calculate Dimensions from a Text String in a single cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am need to calculate the dimensions from cell values that are entered as strings into a single cell vs. 3 separate cells and I do not want to break the dimensions into Length (L) x Width (W) x Height (H) Columns.. instead I am hoping there is a relatively simple function that would allow me to calculate the total cubic dimensions from that single cell.

I am aware of [this tutorial](https://exceljet.net/formula/split-dimensions-into-three-parts) that can take a string and be used to break it into 3 separate cells.. but that defeats the point of what I am trying to do.

My data looks like this:

| Dimensions | Cub/In. | CF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 70x13x13 | 11830 | 6.85 |
| 24*18*13 | 5616 | 3.25 |
| 24x16x12 |  |  |
| 16x24x10 |  |  |

Right now the data is entered as either "LxWxH" or "L*W*H" in that text formant and the columns that have values like the 5616 above are me manually re-entering "=24*18*13".. literally one character difference.

I did try a CONCATENATE to just append an "=" to the beginning but got errors on all in Google Sheets (for comparison) or a Literal string into processed as a formula in Excel.
`=CONCATENATE(“=”,B1)`

[image]

Looking for a simple way to do this calculation in a single column and being able to have to enter the data once or utilize the existing data.   I don't mind doing a single bulk replace of "x" to "*" on the input column to standardize the source column but don't want to have to do a series of bulk replaces every time I want to run through the data.

Thoughts?

Comment: There is also this trick in Excel https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula - would need to substitute * for x in your case. Only included it for interest - the downside is that the sheet then has to be saved as though it contained macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SUBSTITUTE to get them all to the same, then use SPLIT and wrap in PRODUCT:

```
=PRODUCT(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"*","x"),"x"))
```

[image]

Or shorter Version shown by @JvdV:

```
=PRODUCT(SPLIT(A2,"*x"))
```

Comment: Awesome. That ended up being way simpler than I was making it or that other tutorial offered. Thank You

Comment: `=PRODUCT(SPLIT(A2,"*x"))` should do just fine?

Comment: You are correct @JvdV I am not as versed in Google Sheets and did not know that.

Comment: It takes trial and error for me too. Didn't know about this specific behaviour for too long. I also spend some time trying to make this spill results. I came to a long winded `=INDEX(QUERY(Split(A2:A,"*x"),"Select Col1*Col2*Col3 where Col1 is not null label Col1*Col2*Col3 ''"))`